# numpy.loadtxt thinks the last file is empty

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I'm trying to go through my directory and generate an array from each csv file ending in "_chisqtype2_sheet.csv" and append it to the list chisq2data. Everything works fine except the code thinks the last file in H is empty. I tried to add and subtract files and found that regardless of which file is last, the code will always find it to be empty.

```
H=os.listdir(".")
H= [x for x in H if x.endswith("_chisqtype2_sheet.csv")]

chisq2data = []

for fname in H:
    chi2 = np.loadtxt(fname, delimiter=",", skiprows=0)
    chisq2data.append(chi2)
    print fname
    print chi2
```

Printing fname shows that all the files are being found.
Printing chi2 shows the correct arrays for the first files, and an empty array [] for the last file.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure there aren't any empty files in there? How many CSV files do you have that match that condition? What happens if you have only a single file that is certainly not empty?

Comment: What is "the last" file? What happens if you shuffle the entries in H, run your loop, shuffle them again and run it again?

Comment: Are all of your data files saved with the same encoding? This is a strange problem. Also, while I am grasping at straws, are all of the expected file names present (and no extra blank file names) in `print(H)`?

Comment: I tried the above code and could not reproduce this behaviour. It correctly prints the arrays, regardless how many csv files there are (including testing with just 1 csv file). No blanks appeared. Mysterious.